# Are position titles capitalized when the subject is dropped

Tags: grammar

Deputy is not capitalized when referred to as a position.

- “The sheriff had many deputies.”
- “A deputy, a sheriff, and a judge walked into a bar...”

John is capitalized because it is a name.

- “The criminal shot John.”
- “Thank you, John.”

Deputy John is capitalized because it is a title.

- “The criminal shot Deputy John.”
- “Thank you, Deputy John.”

**Question:**
Is deputy capitalized when it is being used as a title and the subject (the noun) is dropped.

Examples:

- “The criminal shot the deputy.” **OR** “The criminal shot the Deputy.”
- “Thank you, deputy.” **OR** “Thank you, Deputy.”

What about:

- “Put your hands in the air!" The *d*eputy shouted. **OR** "Put your hands in the air!" The *D*eputy shouted.

**Edit**

I am not a writer but I wrote a fantasy novel as a way to relax.  I am currently editing right now and I have learned a lot about grammar but I still have many questions.  Sometimes I can find the answers via web searches on English/grammar sites, but this is one question for which I was unable to find an answer.

Most of the use cases would be along the lines of conversation where a persons title is used instead of their name.

Here are some excerpts for references:

- “I would be most grateful for your assistance on the matter, [C/c]onstable.”
- The [C/c]onstable nodded and sat down.

Thanks.

Comment: Where will this be used? There are some situations where you can consult a style guide for a ruling on questions like this.

Comment: It is not a title if it is preceded by an article ("the").

Comment: What's method is excellent for identifying proper/common titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a title precedes a name, it becomes part of the name, and is capitalized:

> I spoke to Constable Fraser this morning.

(You don't use the title and the person's *first* name. Not in American English, anyway.)

When a title comes after a name or stands alone, it's descriptive. It's not a proper adjective or adjective phrase, and therefore is lowercase:

> I spoke to the constable this morning. I spoke to Fraser, who is the constable.

*In your examples:*

The first one is being used as a form of address. I would capitalize it. The name is implied.

> “I would be most grateful for your assistance on the matter, Constable.”

When referring to the same person in the next sentence more broadly, not as a direct adress, lowercase the title:

> The constable nodded and sat down.

Comment: Agreed. If it is a name, or used as a name, it is proper. Otherwise, it is not, no matter the context.

Comment: Just like dear old Dad. My dad taught me a lot.

Comment: I agree with the above examples. When the title becomes a nickname which is capitalized: “I would be most grateful for your assistance on the matter, Constable.”